# How to get localized punctuation rules in .NET?

Tags: .net, internationalization

The .NET Framework has a wide variety of classes to handle culture-specific concerns such as numbers or dates formatting. I was wondering if there was such thing for punctuation.

For example, in English a `:` is located right after the word it follows like in

> Example:

In French, however, it will be

> Exemple :

Most European languages use `.` to mark the end of a sentence. But in Chinese, it is `。`. Same for the quoting characters that may vary from one language to another. I had good hope to find something in the `TextInfo` class or in the `System.Globalization` namespace but no luck.

So I was wondering if such a thing exists natively in the .NET Framework or if there was any third-party library hidden somewhere that was dealing with this kind of problems. I couldn't find any. I am using C# 4.0 but I guess the problem is the same for all the languages supported in .NET.

FYI, I encountered this problem while I wanted to display some culture-independent strings followed by some numeric information like in the following:

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}", this.nameOfAGuy, this.quantityAssociatedWithTheGuy);
```

which is ok in English but not in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.Globalization` namespace doesn't include punctuation rules. Punctuation really is part of linguistic rules (alongside grammar), whereas the globalization namespace is more about national standards.

I don't know if it helps much, but the example you showed can be solved through regular localization. You could --and should-- include format strings (obviously only those that you use to construct display text) in the resources so that localizers can make changes not just to the punctuation, but to anything else that is necessary (another example being the ordering of the substrings, which may need to be reversed in some languages).

```
string.Format(MyResources.FormatNameAndAssociatedQuantity, this.nameOfAGuy, this.quantityAssociatedWithTheGuy);
```

with the English version of this string being `"{0}: {1}"` and its French localization `"{0} : {1}"` (with a space before the colon).